# How to reload echmultiselect extension in yii

Tags: jquery, yii, multi-select, yii-extensions, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using echmultiselect [extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/echmultiselect/) in yii framwork.

I want to add the new option in dropdown when i add any new row in database.Is there any reload parameter in extension or how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery

[example](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#refresh)

code:-

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var el = $("select").multiselect(),
        disabled = $('#disabled'),
        selected = $('#selected'),
        newItem = $('#newItem');

    $("#add").click(function(){
        var v = newItem.val(), opt = $('<option />', {
            value: v,
            text: v
        });

        if(disabled.is(':checked')){
            opt.attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
        if(selected.is(':checked')){
            opt.attr('selected','selected');
        }

        opt.appendTo( el );

        el.multiselect('refresh');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jquery.

```
$('#my_multiselect').multiselect('addOptions', 'my_value=my_text');
```

This will work.